# Using consolidation function in excel sheet with sum function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use consolidation function in vba, where I want to use consolidation feature with sum function in range A1:B50000

note:-work book name will change every time but common name will be  "CF-Insider-Trading-equities"

Here it's the code, I have tried

```
    Range("F1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Consolidate Sources:=Array( _
    "'C:\Users\Windows\Downloads\[CF-Insider-Trading-equities-11-05-2020-to-11-08-2020.csv]CF-Insider-Trading-equities-11-'!R1C1:R5785C2" _
    , _
    "'C:\Users\Windows\Downloads\[CF-Insider-Trading-equities-11-05-2020-to-11-08-2020.csv]CF-Insider-Trading-equities-11-'!R1C1:R5785C2" _
    ), Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
Range("F1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("G1").Select
```

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: You can record a macro while running the consolidate to get the correct code. Though I tried several times and could not get consolidate to run from VBA (nothing happens). The consolidate function may also require xslx files. Last thing - Try opening the source files and selecting a range for consolidation while the consolidation dialog is open in the other file.

Comment: this code is derived from recorded macro only